# Ajax Extension (Timer) stopped working when I retrieve value from DataTable

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

Currently I have an `Ajax Timer` which executes a function every few second. It is working perfectly fine until I tried to retrieve data from a `DataTable`. I have no idea why. I have tried debugging. I even placed label on the page to check.

For example the `Ajax Timer`:

```
Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()

End Sub
```

The datalist (the one giving the problem):

```
Protected Sub dlOrgProfile_ItemCreated(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles dlOrgProfile.ItemCreated
    Dim bizLayerMgmt As BlOrganizations
    Dim dt As DataTable

    bizLayerMgmt = New BlOrganizations()
    dt = bizLayerMgmt.getOrgDetails(userId).Tables(0)

    ddl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("ddlCoType"), DropDownList)
    Dim value As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(0)(3)) 'I have narrowed the problem to this line, if I comment this line.. everything works perfectly
    ddl.SelectedValue = value
End Sub
```

The problem lies in the dt.Rows(0)(3). I have no idea why. I need to use it to retrieve some data from the database.

Just in case if its the front-end side.. here's the markup for the site.

```
<div class="content">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000">
            </asp:Timer>
            <asp:DataList ID="dlOrgProfile" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsOrgDetails" 
                EnableTheming="True" RepeatLayout="Flow" ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <h3>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txBxCoName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OrgName") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                        <div class="ddlSelect">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCoType" runat="server" DataSource='<%# listOrgType() %>' DataTextField="OrganizationType" DataValueField="OrgTypeID" >
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>

                        <h3>
                        </h3>
                        <a id="linkCoImg" href="upload_co_logo.aspx">
                        <asp:Image ID="CoImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/logo/org/default.png" />
                        <span>Change</span> </a>
                        <br />
                        <div id="description">
                            <textarea id="taCoDesc" rows="2" cols="1"><%# Eval("Description") %></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblContacts" runat="server" Text="Contacts:"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <div id="contacts">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbContactOffice" runat="server" CssClass="tbContacts"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbContactFax" runat="server" CssClass="tbContacts"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbContactMail" runat="server" CssClass="tbContacts2"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrgID") %>' 
                            CommandName="save" Text="Save" />

                    </h3>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

Comment: When you say the problem lies at dt.Rows(0)(3), what happens, does it just freeze there?  Does it throw an error that gets swallowed perhaps?  What does it do when you step through it in debug mode?

Comment: When I run the code with dt.Rows(0)(3), it will set the selected value for my dropdownlist but the Ajax Timer simply stopped working. Meaning my Label1 which is supposed to show the current date and time doesn't work. If I comment out the dt.Rows(0)(3), my Ajax Timer will work and Label1 will show the current date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have resolved my own problem.. Still don't really get it why but this is what I did.. Instead of using ItemCreated, I used ItemDataBound.

```
Protected Sub dlOrgProfile_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles dlOrgProfile.ItemDataBound
    Dim bizLayerMgmt As BlOrganizations
    Dim dt As DataTable

    bizLayerMgmt = New BlOrganizations()
    dt = bizLayerMgmt.getOrgDetails(userId).Tables(0)

    ddl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("ddlCoType"), DropDownList)
    Dim value As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(0)(3))
    ddl.SelectedValue = value
End Sub
```